# Prevent WebPack 5 to import and bundle third party libraries?

Tags: webpack, bootstrap-5

I'm writing a sample code with using `Popover` of bootstrap 5
this is my `ts` file:

```
import { Popover } from "bootstrap";

export class MdsPersianDateTimePicker {
  constructor(element: Element) {
   

    this.bsPopover = new Popover(element, {
      container: 'body',
      content: '',
      html: true,
      placement: 'bottom',
      title: ' ',
      trigger: 'manual',
      template: `....`,
      sanitize: false,
    });
  }
}
```

I'm using webpack 5 to bundle my code.

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin = require('webpack-remove-empty-scripts');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'mds.bs.datetimepicker': './src/mds.bs.datetimepicker.ts',
    'mds.bs.datetimepicker.style': './src/mds.bs.datetimepicker.style.css',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.tsx?$/,
      use: 'ts-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    }, {
      test: /.s?css$/,
      use: [{
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          options: {}
        },
        'css-loader'
      ],
    }],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true
  },
  watch: false,
  devServer: {
    lazy: false,
    watchContentBase: true
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        extractComments: false,
      }),
      new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    }),
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({
      banner: `
Bootstrap 5+ Persian Date Time Picker Plugin
.....
      `
    })
  ]
};
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

every thing is OK but when I use `npm run webpack` bootstrap 5 is included in the bundled file!
I didn't want it and I just want to bundle my ts file.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/?

Comment: do you do application(then `externals` is way to go, but you need to make bootstrap available from `window`) or library(then you probably don't need webpack at all to publish your code)?

Comment: I'm working on a Library. @skyboyer

Comment: so maybe you don't need a bundler? if you want to publish your library in ES5, you can just process your JS files with Babel but still keep them separately from each other. This way no dependency will be bundled as well. Sure, if you want you may go with bundling but then your will need your library's consumer to expose bootstrap to global variable in order to use it through `externals`. The more efforts for library's user, the harder things go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to my `webpack.config.js`, my problem solved:

```json
  externals: {
    bootstrap: 'bootstrap',
  },
```

my `webpack.config.js` completely:

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin = require('webpack-remove-empty-scripts');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'mds.bs.datetimepicker': './src/mds.bs.datetimepicker.ts',
    'mds.bs.datetimepicker.style': './src/mds.bs.datetimepicker.style.css',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.tsx?$/,
      use: 'ts-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    }, {
      test: /.s?css$/,
      use: [{
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          options: {}
        },
        'css-loader'
      ],
    }],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  externals: {
    bootstrap: 'bootstrap',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true
  },
  watch: false,
  devServer: {
    lazy: false,
    watchContentBase: true
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        extractComments: false,
      }),
      new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    }),
    new webpack.BannerPlugin({
      banner: `
.
.
.
version : 4.0.0
      `
    })
  ]
};
```